# Remove a JPanel with a JButton [JAVA]

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border, jbutton

I have the class with the Frame:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Menu_Frame extends JFrame{

    Menu_Panel menu_panel = new Menu_Panel();

    public Menu_Frame(){
        Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();      
        Dimension screenSize = kit.getScreenSize();
        int screenHeight = screenSize.height;
        int screenWidth = screenSize.width;

        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        getContentPane().add(menu_panel);   
    }
}
```

Here i have the panel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Menu_Panel extends JPanel{

    Play_Button play = new Play_Button();

    public Menu_Panel() {

        Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();      
        Dimension screenSize = kit.getScreenSize();
        int screenHeight = screenSize.height;
        int screenWidth = screenSize.width;
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        setLocation(0,0);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        add(play);
    }
}
```

And here i have the button class:

```
public class Play_Button extends JButton implements ActionListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5408317246901761857L;

    protected int size_x = 150;
    protected int size_y = 75;
    protected int location_x = 0;
    protected int location_y = 0;

    Font f= new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 30);
    String title = "PLAY";

    Menu_Frame frame;
    Menu_Panel menu;

    public Play_Button() {

        setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 25));
        setText(title);

        Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();      
        Dimension screenSize = kit.getScreenSize();
        location_x = (screenSize.height/2)+180;
        location_y = screenSize.width/5;

        setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20));
        setSize(size_x,size_y);
        setLocation(location_x,location_y);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setForeground(Color.RED);
        setFocusPainted(false);
        setBorderPainted(false);
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        setVisible(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(100,100);
        panel.setLocation(100, 100);
        panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        panel.setVisible(true);

        addActionListener(this);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
                setBorderPainted(true);
                setForeground(Color.RED);

            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
                setBorderPainted(false);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.getContentPane().remove(menu);
    }
}
```

And Finally here i have the class for round the border of play_button:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class RoundedBorder implements Border {

    private int radius;


    RoundedBorder(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }


    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return new Insets(this.radius+1, this.radius+1, this.radius+2, this.radius);
    }


    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return true;
    }
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        g.drawRoundRect(x, y, width-1, height-1, radius, radius);
    }
}
```

Now, the panel doesn't disappear when i click the button, and i don't know why. I try with a CarLayout, with setVisible(false), but it doesn't work. How can i fix it?

Comment: I would advice against using `Toolkit#getScreenSize` this way, as it doesn't take into account additional OS elements, like the task bar or dock. As a general user recommendation, don't set the size of the main frame, instead simply allow the preferred size to be the packed size and expand the frame to it's OS maximum using `setExtendedState` as you have

Comment: `setSize`, `setBounds`, `setLocation` are all irrelevant while the components are under the control of a layout manager. Also, components are visible by default

Comment: The most common answer to your question is - use a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 0):

## Preambule...

I would advice against using `Toolkit#getScreenSize` this way, as it doesn't take into account additional OS elements, like the task bar or dock. As a general user recommendation, don't set the size of the main frame, instead simply allow the preferred size to be the packed size and expand the frame to it's OS maximum using `setExtendedState` as you have

`setSize`, `setBounds`, `setLocation` are all irrelevant while the components are under the control of a layout manager. Also, components are visible by default.

## Core...

Removing a component is the opposite of adding one (no, seriously).  Simply call `remove` on the container which contains the component, passing a reference of the component you want to remove.  When you're done updating the UI, simply call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container to trigger a layout and paint pass.

Having said that, generally speaking, it's much better to make use of a `CardLayout`, which provides you the ability to simply switch between different views.

See [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your `actionPerformed` method

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    frame.getContentPane().remove(menu);
}
```

`frame` and `menu` are declared fields of `Play_Button`, but are never set to anything

If you print out what they are, they should be null

When you create your button, make sure to set those two fields:

```
Menu_Panel menu_panel = new Menu_Panel();
menu_panel.play.menu = menu_panel;
menu_panel.play.frame = this;
```

While this may work, it is not great program flow